# h:outputLink jsf, hide the external link

Tags: jsf

I want to make a simple link to an external page in JSF. I have this code:

```
<h:outputLink value ="http://www.google.com.co/" >
<h:outputText value="¿No puede acceder a su cuenta?" />
</h:outputLink>
```

But the result is :

```
¿No puede acceder a su cuenta?
(www.google.com.co)
```

I dont want that my target (www.google.com.co) appears in the link... 
First: Is this the way to do it? 
Second: How can I hide the target of the link?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink) explanation for understanding the use of `h:outputLink`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is, instead of linking to an URL, the link is a JavaScript function with an encoded parameter, which then replaces the current page with the decoded URL, or opens it in a new page.

Answer (score 0):

In context to the above code, you can use the code I've written below:

```
<h:outputLink value="destinationPage.xhtml">¿No puede acceder a su cuenta?</h:outputLink>
```